# Log in issues in 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, unity

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and since updating the kernel via the update manager from 3.2.0-110 to 3.5.0-18 I am having a peculiar issue.
When starting the computer Ubuntu will load the log in screen repeatedly in very quick succession. It takes about half a minute before it stabilises and I can finally log in. The computer works fine after log in, only sometimes it will randomly log out the session.

I am not sure what causes the problem. 
Based on similar questions I reconfigured `light dm` but this led to the problem that I couldn't log in as I got a low-graphic error. This error also occasionally persists. 
Sometimes after log in there is an error report, one time concerning `xorg` and another was for `unity-greeter`.

Does anyone have suggestions how to fix this problem?

Comment: Which gub version you are using?

Comment: Grub version is 1.99-21ubuntu3.19.

Answer (score 1):

I may suggest you to reinstall the grub.

In terminal do:

sudo update-grub

you will see now in which partition Ubuntu is installed (most of the time is this sda)

Then reinstall grub:

sudo grub-install /dev/sda

( sda can be different in your system ).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try this once I have reinstalled the most recent kernel. For the time being I switched back to 3.2.0-110 as I needed to have a functioning computer for work.

Comment: When you are working with the most recent kernel, do you have  the same problem when you start the computer in recovery mode?

Comment: Is this not the solution for your problem : http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: The recovery mode worked. The link you gave I tried toe bottom solution in the first answer, reinstalling lightdm, but that didn't work. On my current kernel (3.2.0-110) I do have troubles that sometimes the boot doesn't work as the computer goes in low-graphics-mode. So there is certainly seems to be something amiss with the graphic drivers.

Comment: I think you have wright. This is probably an “old” computer.  You can do 2 things: first is waiting until another kernel version is coming out, or second simply stay with the kernel version that work

Comment: I actually ran into more serious problems, Ubuntu not working at all anymore, so I did a clean installation of 14.04. Working perfectly now again. Was time to switch after 4 year anyway.

Comment: If your computer have enough memory: 16.04 is working fine to.